# How to add different views in pagecontroller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uipagecontrol

I want to add 4 views in  page controller .I have used scroll view with page controller. I have used this codes
**viewDidLoad**

```
[super viewDidLoad];
NSMutableArray *views=[[NSMutableArray alloc ]initWithObjects:v1.view,v2.view,v3.view,v4.view,nil];
for (int i=0; i<views.count; i++) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x=self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y=0;
    frame.size=self.scrollView.frame.size;
    UIView *subview=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    subview=[views objectAtIndex:i];
    //[subview addSubview:[views objectAtIndex:i]];
    [v1.view addSubview:subview];
    [subview release];
```

Here view1,view2,view3,view4 are refference of 4 different views.
Any one can help me regarding this,please?

Answer (score 0):

That looks right, but have you set the contentSize of the scrollview to CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * 4, scrollView.frame.size.height) ?

Comment: Yes ,I have done this  self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake((self.scrollView.frame.size.width * views.count), self.scrollView.frame.size.height);                 But still its not comming.

Answer (score 0):

The V1 ,V2,V3,V4 are view controllers i guess.
Are they properly initialized and have a valid memory?
check

```
NSLog(@"%@",[v1 description]);
```